# add only specific colums in array - python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, lets say

```
A = array([ [a11, a12, a13], [a21, a22, a23], [a31, a32, a33] ])
B = array([ [b11, b12, b13], [b21, b22, b23], [b31, b32, b33] ])
```

and I want to get (EDITED)

```
C = array([ [a11, a12+b12, a13], [a21, a22+b22, a23], [a31, a32+b32, a33] ])
```

I could achieve this with for-loop, but I believe there must be a more elegant way in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not simply do the following:

```
C = A.copy()
C[1] += B[1]    # (or appropriate indexes)
```

OK -- edited solution:

```
C = A.copy()
C[:,1] += B[:,1]
```

Comment: sorry I wrote the C array wrong. It's supposed to be
C = array([ [a11, a12+b12, a13], [a21, a22+b22, a23], [a31, a32+b32, a33] ])

Comment: but I see your answer is correct anyway - I can just use
C = A.copy()
C[:,1] += B[:,1]
works fine